# Terraform - How to create Azure Kubernetes Cluster with AGIC that creates an App Gateway with Private IP

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to create a AKS Kubernetes cluster with `ingress_application_gateway` add-on which will create an Application Gateway. I am using `terraform` to create this. Please refer to my terraform code below.

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s_cluster" {
  
  . . . 

  private_cluster_enabled = true
  

  ingress_application_gateway {
    gateway_name = "${var.cluster_name}-agic"
    subnet_cidr = "172.29.20.0/22" 
  }


  . . . 

}
```

And above code will create a Cluster with AGIC (Application Gateway Ingress Controller) installed.

So far everything is working fine.

Then I try to deploy an application with an `ingress` as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: aspnetapp
  labels:
    app: aspnetapp
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: aspnetapp-image
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      protocol: TCP

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aspnetapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: aspnetapp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"  
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aspnetapp
            port:
              number: 80
```

This will create a `pod`, a `service`, and an `ingress` as expected.

**But I need this pod to be internal (that it should be exposed through an ingress with a private IP)** and that's the reason why I have put `appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"` in the Ingress annotations.

But I get the following error:

> 'Warning' reason: 'NoPrivateIP' ignoring Ingress default/minimal-ingress as it requires Application Gateway test-svg-cluster-agic has a private IP address

This is because the Application Gateway Created when the ingress is created doesn't have a Private IP.

But also it is not possible to set these conditions (that the application gateway creates by the ingress should have a private ip along with the public ip) in the `terraform` as well, because all the supporting parameters for the `ingress_application_gateway` block is as follows:

- gateway_id - The ID of the Application Gateway to integrate with the ingress controller of this Kubernetes Cluster.
- gateway_name - The name of the Application Gateway to be used or created in the Nodepool Resource Group, which in turn will be integrated with the ingress controller of this Kubernetes Cluster.
- subnet_cidr - The subnet CIDR to be used to create an Application Gateway, which in turn will be integrated with the ingress controller of this Kubernetes Cluster.
- subnet_id - ID of the subnet

How can I specify in the `terraform` code so when an ingress is created, the `AGIC` will provision an application gateway also with a private IP instead of just having a public IP?

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to create the application gateway with an azurerm_application_gateway resource, then reference it with the gateway_id property of the ingress_application_gateway block.